# C++ Sorting Class String Array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, sorting

I've worked for the past few days on this project. My problem is when it comes to the sort function, it falls apart. I feel I am missing a parameter of the 'sort' function. Maybe more seasoned eyes can see my error. The objective is to have the user input a string, apply it to an array of `class person`, sort, then print to console. The input section works perfectly, but the sort function will not even compile, I did not include that portion, but if it is needed I will post that as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

//class declaration

class Person{
public:
    string lastName;
    string firstName;
};

//variables

int entry; // defined in other function
string choice; //defined in other function

//arrays

Person nameArray[10];

//function declarations

void sortView(){

    sort(nameArray[0].lastName.begin(), nameArray[0].lastName.end() + entry);

    for (int i = 0; i < entry; i++){
        cout << nameArray[i].lastName;
        cout << ", ";
        cout << nameArray[i].firstName;
        cout << endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: Look at the doc for [sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) thats not how it works *at all*

Comment: The problem is that all the documentation for sort refers to using int data types, for this assignment the input has to be string. I am well aware that string at their base level are int values, but I don't understand what I am missing.

Comment: yeah so? the doc i linked to shows how to use a custom comparison function which is *exactly* what you need. The fact that the examples uses an int and not a string is not relevant.

Comment: There's no reason to use `unsigned int` in your functions, as you currently have it, just use `int` for simplicity. I provided an edit which removed those.

Answer (score 1):

`std::sort`() takes two required parameters: the beginning iterator value and the ending iterator value that defines the sequence to be sorted.

What you're passing to `std::sort`() does not look remotely like a pair of iterators. It doesn't even compile.

`NameArray.lastName` is not valid C++. `NameArray` is an array. The `.` operator is used with structures or classes, not with arrays.

To sort this ten-element array you would normally use:

```
sort(NameArray, NameArray+10);
```

taking advantage of the fact that using an array's name in an expression gives you the pointer to the first element of the array, and these pointers will be logically equivalent to iterators, in this context.

However, this won't work either, here, because it is not defined how elements of `NameArray` can be compared. `NameArray` contains instances of a `person` class, and you can meaningfully sort something only if you can compare different values using the `<` operator, to sort lesser values before the greater values, of course.

In order to sort this array you will also need to either:

1) Pass the third, optional parameter to `std::sort`(), a lambda that compares two instances of the `person` class, or

2) Implement an `operator<` member method in the `person` class.

Answer (score 1):

```
sort(std::begin(NameArray), std::end(NameArray), [](const person& p1, const person& p2) {
    // write your sort logic, for example
    return p1.lastName < p2.lastName;
});
```

For `std::sort`, you need to provide two iterators and a compare function

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this isn't how arrays work.

`NameArray` will give a pointer to the first element of the array, `NameArray + 10` will give a pointer to the eleventh element, but `NameArray.lastName` doesn't exist. `NameArray` is an *array*, not a person. What is the last name of the array?

What you want to do is apply `sort` to `NameArray`, and sort it based on its last name. It is applied to `NameArray`, so it should be:

`sort(NameArray, NameArray + entry)`.

Now you will have another compilation error. The [sorting function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) needs a way to compare two `person` (and you should start your class names with an uppercase!).

There are two ways to do this. You can consider that a `person` is always inferior to another based on their `lastName`, in which case you will overload the `<` operator of `person`.

Or you will specify a special way to compare elements to your sort function:

```
sort(NameArray, NameArray + entry, [](const person &p1, const person &p2) {
    return p1.lastName < p2.lastName;
});
```

Do [some reading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) to understand a bit more, you can also look up lambda functions.

---

PS: Keep the names starting with an uppercase being your classes, naming variables like that is confusing.

You may also want to look up `std::vector` or `std::valarray` as alternatives to using a fixed-size array.